# Removing extension of multiple file without using loop in linux

Tags: files, filenames, rename

Sample files:

```
RBFATL001USCGA002.--K1234--
RCAVTL001USCGA043.--K2135--
```

Output:

```
RBFATL001USCGA002
RCAVTL001USCGA043
```

Comment: Why do want to do it without loop? Have you tried any solutions ?

Comment: Did you look at the `rename` command. It's perfect for this job, just give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

There will always have to be a  loop. Possibly you mean you want a tool that hides that looping to you?

Then, you could use `perl`'s `rename` (sometimes called `prename` or `perl-rename`):

```
rename 's/\.[^.]+\.*\z//s' ./*.*
```

Or `zsh`'s `zmv`:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*).[^.]##.#' '$1'
```

Those would by default not rename hidden files (those whose name starts with a `.`). If you wanted to process those as well, you'd do:

```
zmv '(?*).[^.]##.#(#qD)' '$1'
```

Those consider that in `.foo.bar.`, the extension is `.bar.` (and don't consider `foo...` to have an extension). You can adapt if you want to consider it being `.` instead (`zmv '(?*).*(#qD)' '$1'`). I don't expect you'd want to consider it being `.foo.bar.` (which `zmv '*(#qD)' '${f%%.*}'` would strip (but fail as a file can't have an empty name)).

Also note that in `file.tar.gz`, the extension is considered to be `.gz`, not `.tar.gz`.

To do it recursively:

```
zmv '(**/)(?*).[^.]##.#(#qD)' '$1$2'
```

Or  with `rename`:

```
find . -depth -name '?*.*' -exec rename 's/\.[^./]+\.*\z//s' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach without using loop.

```
find . -type f -name "?*.*" -exec sh -c 'mv -v "$0" "${0%.*}"' '{}' \;
```